# Output custom field as ul list

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom field who's content I would like to output as a ul list.

The custom field contains words that are separated with a spaces between.

I'm trying to use this code here but it's not working.

```
    <?php
    $list_items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'idid');

         if($list_items){
            $list_items = explode(" ", $list_items) {
                echo '<ul>';
                    foreach($list_items as $list_item)
                        echo '<li>' . $list_item . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `get_post_meta` incorrectly. As you use it, it will return an array - you cannot explode an array. See [the codex on get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta);

If you pass `true` as the third parameter, this tells the function to return a string. So,

```
$list_items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'idid', true);
```

should work.